# R code to estimate parameters from non-linear function

Tags: r, parameters, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have a data set. There are some categorical variables and some numerical variables. I want to estimate the parameters of a model `e^{X'b}` for every categories and others. I am trying to do it in R code. I need to do it by creating design matrix for categorical variables like `age==2` and `age==3`, where considering `age==1` as reference category. But this program is not running and giving errors. What is the problem?

```
sex <- c("F","M","F","M","F","M")
age <- c(1,3,2,3,1,2) # categorical variable with three age categories 
age <- as.factor(age)
dat <- data.frame(sex,age)
myfun <- function(par, data){
  xx <- data
  func <- exp(par[1]*(xx$age==2)+par[2]*(xx$age==3)+par[3]*factor(xx$sex))
  return(-func)
}
optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4,0.7), data=dat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `myfun` returns a vector of length 6 (because you multiply with `xx$sex`). It needs to be of length 1. Also, the `optim` function takes the `par` first and the function as second parameter.

EDIT: You need to rewrite your function to return a single value. `-exp(X'b)` is a vector of length of your observations. Maybe this goes in your direction:

```
myfun1 <- function(par, data) {
   xx <- matrix(c(as.numeric(dat$sex), age, rep(1, nrow(dat))), ncol=3)
   sum(-exp(xx %*% par))
}
optim(c(0.1,0.4,0.7), myfun1, data=dat)
```

Note that it would be more efficient to pass `xx` to `optim` since the calculation of `xx` is independent of the iteration.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what your `myfun` is supposed to return. Maybe write out a formula without code. That would help me understand you better.

Comment: My function is myfun=exp(X'b). Where, X is the covariate and b is the parameter.

Comment: Are there observed values you want to fit your model and explanatory variables to? This looks like a common model to me, maybe there is a package for this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes these are explanatory variables. I have a large data set. Do you know any kind of R package name which can do it?

Comment: Have a look at ?glm (with log link function) and ?nls function in base R first.